# Are weekly CRON jobs possbile for for openFDA, new indications_and_usage inquiries?

Tags: api, openfda

How would I track new FDA drug indications or other major changes each month?
Example Dupixent expanded its atopic dermatitis indication from 12 years + to 6 years + in May 2020.

How could I set up a CRON job to check for new indications each week or month?
e.g. ' indications_and_usage ' family, 'purpose' parameter
e.g.  'Other fields' family, 'recent_major_changes' parameter

Example Inquiry:
[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20110501+TO+20121231]&limit=1](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:%5B20110501+TO+20121231%5D&limit=1)

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly said, you could set up a periodic job that runs the query and compares results looking for changes, additions, etc. Unfortunately, we are unable to provide guidance for configuring a particular tool for doing so, such as CRON. CRON has vast documentation available all over the Web, however.